# save python array list as .json, reload with tf.io.read_file, tf.io.decode_json-example

Tags: python, json, tensorflow

I have a list with many numpy arrays, created by for example:

```
data_ = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
dataset = np.array(data_), dtype=np.float)
```

then use stack to concat many many lists ->

```
dataset = np.dstack((dataset, np.array(data_)))
```

giving `dataset = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]], ...]`

I saved this dataset as json file using

```
f = open(file_path, 'w')
json.dump(corpus, f)
f.close()
```

I used to load this json file using json.load(file_path) and loading dataworked perfectly fine.

But now, the number of data and size of data is huge, so I'm trying to u use

```
data = json.loads(file_path)
data = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
data = tf.io.decode_json_example(data)
label = self.get_label(file_path)
```

where it gives me an error:
TypeError: in user code:

```
 /home/tf_dataset_loader.py:84 process_data  *
        data = json.loads(file_path)
    /usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py:347 loads  *
        raise TypeError('the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '

    TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Tensor'
> /home/tf_loader.py(75)load_data()
-> for data, label in train_ds.map(self.process_data).take(4):
```

I'm not familiar with json that much, but I used it because I needed to save and reload list data, and csv/xlsx/txt won't give me list as I saved when I load it back.

I'm wondering if I have a way to save json file in a better way, so I can re-load it back with tensorflow.

Comment: Where did you set the file_path variable?

Comment: it's in other code, before loading. but the shape of file_path is for example, file_path = 'data_1.json'
I have .csv file with list of file directories, and I loaded csv file using 
        data_lists =  tf.data.Dataset.list_files('data_list.csv')
        for data, label in data_lists.map(self.process_image):
                  print(data)

Comment: For anyone who is struggling with similar issues, I have converted all JSON files to .npy files. FYI, you might also try and use the .npz file type, I'd like to try it later myself. And also, if there are any faster ways or how to use JSON files in a better way, it's be highly appreciated if you could share that with me! Thank you!